# React Component vs Stateless Functional Components

Tags: react

Sei que no React existem dois tipos de declaração para um componente.

***React Component***

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Elemento/>
    );
  }
}
```

***React Stateless Functional Components***

```
const App = () => (
  return <Elemento/>
);
```

O *React Component* permite o uso dos estados e essa é uma diferença entre as declarações. No entanto, tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Existe diferenças extras (fora a questão do estado) entre o uso das declarações?
- Usar os *stateless components* quando não precisa de estado trará uma performance melhor?
- Quais as principais vantagens dos *stateless components* em relação a declaração normal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Existe diferenças extras (fora a questão do estado) entre o uso das
>   declarações?

Sim e não. É possível, pelo menos em teoria, realizar tudo o que você faria com *stateless components* com *class components* (o contrário não é verdadeiro, mais sobre isso na sequencia), mas o *approach* deve ser de acordo com o objetivo que você quer atingir. Existem casos onde o uso de *stateless components* é o mais adequado pelo simples fato do estado não ser necessário (como o nome já implica).

*Stateless components* são, de maneira simplicada, a representação de um estado passado para um método de *render* via *props*. Um componente de botão seria um bom exemplo:

```
const Button = props => (
   <button className={props.className}>
      {props.label}
   </button>
);
```

Este componente tem como único propósito renderizar as *props*, e essa é a unica coisa que ele deveria fazer. Essas *props* podem vir de um estado (ou qualquer outra coisa) de um componente mais alto na cadeia, mas, do ponto de vista do componente encapsulado, o estado não existe e, portanto, é imutável. Isso também representa um pouco da [natureza funcional](https://medium.com/@agm1984/an-overview-of-functional-programming-in-javascript-and-react-part-one-10d75b509e9e) que é possível se atingir com o React, utilizando alguns conceitos da [Programação Funcional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). Sem entrar muito em detalhes, funções puras são aquelas cujo resultado é sempre o mesmo, dado o mesmo *set* de dados iniciais. Pode-se entender que a função `Button` que eu criei é, portanto, pura. O retorno, neste caso em especial, é um elemento JSX.

Ainda, *stateless components* não permitem acesso ao [ciclo de vida](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) do React e aos *hooks*, como `componentDidMount()` e similares, o que já é possível de se fazer com *class Components*. É comum fazer busca de dados em uma API, por exemplo, usando o `componentDidMount()`, ou destruir objetos e desalocar recursos em `componentWillUnmount()`. Isso só é possível em componentes escritos em forma de classe

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Code ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Code ...
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Code ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Code ...
    )
  }
}
```

Ou seja, do ponto de vista teórico, cada uma das declarações tem um uso bem específico. Do ponto de vista prático, é possível fazer tudo com componentes em forma de classe, mas nem sempre vale a pena. O que nos leva a próxima pergunta:

> Usar os stateless components quando não precisa de estado trará uma
>   performance melhor?

[Esse cara](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/136096/) fez o teste. Instanciou vários componentes funcionais e vários componentes de classe e mediu o tempo de render de cada um deles. No final das contas, a diferença performática é desprezível. Mas existe uma diferença fundamental entre eles que é o código transpilado para o ES5. Veja a diferença de um componente funcional transpilado

```
var MyStatelessComponent = function MyStatelessComponent(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    props.name
  );
}
```

Para um componente de classe, depois do mesmo processo:

```
var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }
function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }
var MyComponentClass = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(MyComponentClass, _React$Component);
function MyComponentClass() {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyComponentClass);
return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (MyComponentClass.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(MyComponentClass)).apply(this, arguments));
  }
_createClass(MyComponentClass, [{
    key: "render",
    value: function render() {
      return React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        this.props.name
      );
    }
  }]);
return MyComponentClass;
}(React.Component);
```

Pensando em uma aplicação que tenha um número elevado de componentes, esse código pode ser potencialmente gerado para cada um deles, gerando um JavaScript de produção extremamente grande. O que significa que

> Quais as principais vantagens dos stateless components em relação a
>   declaração normal?

De bate pronto, uma vantagem palpável é o código gerado ser menor. Outra vantagem é que a programação funcional (i.e., *stateless function components*) é menos *error prone*, então você pode acabar gerando uma base de código mais sólida no caso de componentes onde o estado não é importante. Um [HOC](https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/handle-loadings-in-react-by-using-higher-order-components-2ee8de9c3deb) para trabalhar com o tempo de *loading* de componentes, por exemplo, pode ser facilmente criado funcionalmente e é muito mais fácil de se manter. Outro ponto é a separação de responsabilidades. Se você não precisa do estado, use algo que lhe entregue exatamente isso, evitando o *overkill*.

Se a única ferramenta que conhecemos é um martelo, tudo vai se parecer com um prego. Partindo dessa máxima, é bom conhecer todo o *toolset* do react e saber quando usar o quê.

Conclusão: Um componente funcional não tem estado, não acesso aos métodos do ciclo de vida e é mais fácil de ser escrito já que é uma função. (Trivia: é possível criar componentes funcionais como métodos de uma classe que representa um componente de classe. Abre possibilidades para várias coisas). Já um componente de classe tem estado e permite acesso aos métodos do ciclo de vida. Se você precisa manter o estado da UI encapsulado no componente, a solução com classes é a mais adequada. Vale lembrar que o react vai instanciar um objeto toda vez que o render ocorrer, o que pode levar, em casos extremos, a problemas de memória. Então, se você detectar componentes que podem ser escritos como funcionais, escreva-os.

Comment: Show Caio! Muito boa a resposta! Obrigado por compartilhar!